# Uploading CSV file from react front end to node.js backend and storing it in the folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, csv, upload, backend

I'm trying to upload a file to the backend folder using react's front end form input but I'm unable to do so.

I've added the form, I tried capturing data in the state but for some reason I can't store csv file in a state, is it because of file complexity?

Since I couldn't get the state to store my csv, I used axios to push data straight to the backend which seemed to work but the file was not saved in the backend.

I have 3 files, react App and node Upload

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import CSVReader from 'react-csv-reader';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      apiResponse: '',
      file: null,
    };
    this.handleImport = this.handleImport.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  callAPI() {
      fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")
          .then(res => res.text())
          .then(res => this.setState({ apiResponse: res }));
          console.log(this.state.apiResponse)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.callAPI();
  }

  handleImport(data){

    this.setState({file:data.target.files[0]})

    //because I couldn't get state to work I used axios imediately with the data
    axios.post("http://localhost:9000/upload", data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data 
    }).then(res => { // then print response status
        console.log(res.statusText)
    })

  }

  //I'm not using handlesubmit here as it involves a button press 
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', this.state.file);

    console.log(data);

    axios.post("http://localhost:9000/upload", data, { // receive two parameter endpoint url ,form data 
    }).then(res => { // then print response status
        console.log(res.statusText)
    })
  } 


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p className='App-intro'> {this.state.apiResponse}</p>
        </header>

        <content className='body_cont'>

          {/* My Form */}
          <form action="POST">
            <input type="file" name='file' onChange={this.handleImport} />
            <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Upload File</button>
          </form>  

        </content>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Next file is my upload file for which the routes have been set in app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '../folder1/folder2/dm-portal/in')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname )
  }
  });

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file')

router.post('/',function(req, res) {

    console.log(req)

    upload(req, res, function (err) {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
                return res.status(500).json(err)
            } else if (err) {
                return res.status(500).json(err)
            }
        return res.status(200).send(req.file)

    })

  });



module.exports = router;
```

End results is I get a whole bunch of warning but the axios seemed to be working, however, the files is not being saved.

Any help appreciated.

P.S. I'm beginner.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with multer but when I've used it you are supposed to set the destination folder of where you'd like the upload to happen like so:

const upload = multer({ dest: 'path-to/store-file', filename: Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname });

I also don't recognize your syntax on the router. Should look more like this: 
router.post('/', upload.any(), function(req, res) {
// DO SOMETHING
});

Comment: I'm getting an error if I use upload.any() in the router.